# iOS 6 MFMessageComposeViewController missing message body text field

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I seem to have a problem with the built in message composer. I'm trying to send an SMS via MFMessageComposeViewController , everything else seems to work fine but the message text field is missing after the composer has opened (i can see the recipient).

Could it be a bug? I'm on iPhone 5 with 6.1.3.

How i call the composer:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        NSString* phoneNumber = [selectedContact getSMSPhoneNumber];
        if(![phoneNumber isEqualToString: @"[None]"]){
            controller.body = @"Dude this is some text";
            controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: phoneNumber, nil];
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        }else{
            // Not yet implemented
        }
    }
```

MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            [self showErrorAlert];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I tried composing an email with MFMailComposeViewController and I don't have any problem with that. It only seems to affect the MessageComposer.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck on a similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could just to test if it works use this code to set the bodie

```
NSString *emailBody = @"Your string";
[controller setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: I'm not sending an email, but i have tried: [controller setBody: emailBody ]; Still not working.

Comment: The question is about `MFMessageComposeViewController`, not `MFMailComposeViewController`.